# Accessing an element by index of EventTarget type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access an **input** element on a `event.target` object using `event.target[0]` in TypeScript but I keep getting this error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'EventTarget'.
Property '0' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

This is my code so far:

```
const counterDecrement = document.getElementById("counter__decrement")!;
const counterIncrement = document.getElementById("counter__increment")!;
const counterForm = document.getElementById("counter__form")!;

counterDecrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  counterValue.innerText = (+counterValue.innerText - 1).toString();
});

counterIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  counterValue.innerText = (+counterValue.innerText + 1).toString();
});

counterForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  if (event.target) {
    console.log(event.target[0]);
  }
});
```

I get a squiggly red line under `event.target[0]` (line 18)

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: you can access it via counterForm 
like this: counterForm.elements[0]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now, I'm getting "Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'." error.

Comment: aha, let me post pure answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can access it via counterForm's elements and you need to set what kind of html element is counterForm

you can simply use it in this way :

```
const counterForm = document.getElementById("counter__form") as HTMLFormElement;
counterForm.elements[0];
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error. But if I want to access the value of that element. How would I got about it? I get:

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Sorry I should have been more explicit with the problem from the start

Comment: Fixed by setting ```const counterFormInput = counterForm.elements[0] as HTMLInputElement;```

Comment: that's right,good job